# How to batch inputs together for tensorflow?

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow

I'm trying to batch together the inputs for a neural network I'm working on so I can feed them into tensorflow like in the tensorflow MNIST tutorial. However I can't find anyway of doing this and it isn't covered in the tutorial.

```
input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [10, 10])
...
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))
inputs = #A list containing 50 of the inputs
sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={input: inputs})
```

This will throw the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (50, 10, 10) for Tensor'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(10, 10)'
```

I understand that why I'm getting the above error, I just don't know how to get tensorflow to treat my inputs as a batch of inputs rather than think I'm trying to feed it all in as one shape.

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the signature of your placeholder. Let's break down the error message:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (50, 10, 10) for 
Tensor'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(10, 10)'
```

your `inputs` variable is the one that has shape `(50, 10, 10)` that means `50` elements of shape `(10, 10)` and Tensor `Placeholder:0` is your `input` variable. If you print (input.name you will get the value `Placeholder:0`. 
*Cannot feed value* means that it cannot assign `inputs` to `input`.

A first quick solution is to fix the shape of the placeholder `input` to

```
input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [50, 10, 10])
```

but each time you want to modify the size of the batch you will need to update the batch size in your input. 
A better way to specify the batch size is to put a undefined shape dimension for the batch size using `None`:

```
input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10, 10])
```

This now will works with any batch size, from `1` to the hardware limits of your architecture.

Comment: Thanks so much the [None, 10, 10] thing was really what I was looking for. That actually was in the tutorial it just didn't click in my head that's what it was for.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to setup your input differently to have shape [batch_size, 10, 10], and use the parameter `reduction_indices` when calling tf.reduce_mean(). As an aside, `tf.contrib.learn.read_batch_examples()` would take care of batching the examples using a batch queue, see documentation [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard6/tf.contrib.learn.read_batch_examples.md).