# Is it possible to feed multiple images input to convolutional neural network

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset of many images where images have 5 magnifications (x10, x20, x30, x40, x50) to the same class but they are not a sequence data, and all images are in RGB mode and with size 512x512  and I want to give this 5 images as an input to the CNN, and I don't know how.
Also, there is another problem which is once the model was well trained on the 5 image pipeline, is it okay or will it work, when I have only one image (one magnification, x10 as an example)?

Comment: See the accepted answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40685452/how-to-batch-inputs-together-for-tensorflow

Comment: @bogatron i don't think so, also i am working on Keras, and i don't have experience in TensorFlow

Comment: The you should tag your question `keras` instead of `tensorflow`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have asked two questions.
For the 1st one, there are two ways to do it. 1- you can design the model in a way that the input size is 5×512×512×3, and you go to train the model.

For your 2nd question, you need to design your model in a way to handle a `feature absence` or missing features. For a complicated one, that I can think about, you can design the model in this way,
You have 5 inputs, per image, and each image goes through one or more CNN, and after one or a few layers you merge those together.
For each input, you can consider an additional feature, a boolean to indicate if this current image should be considered in training or not ( is absent or present). During your training, you should make a combination of all 5, and also consider the absence of some, so that your model learns to handle the absence of one or more images out of 5 in the input.
I hope I was clear enough and it helps.
Good luck.

Comment: I thought in 2 ideas:
1- to put the 5 images in the same batch.
2- to use CNN-LSTM 
So what do you think ?

Comment: 1- Cons for this approach is that during the test, per one of 5 you will classify, which means you do not use the whole information for making a decision. Although you can make a majority vote or something like that as a post processing trick, but you still have upto 5 separate calssification, and you do not use the shared information in the classification part.  2- Using LSTM might work, but logically i do not see why one should consider a sequenece between 5 different images.